# Split and format text output with separators Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have an entry and label I want to format my text to my label like this:

> "email@gmail.com", "email2@gmail.com", "email3@gmail.com"

this is what I enter in my entry field:

> email@gmail.com /space/ email2@gmail.com /space/ email3@gmail.com 
> or
>   email@gmail.com,email2@gmail.com,email3@gmail.com

The separator is a space or comma. How can I format my output to the one above?

Comment: So what you want exactly as the output is this  "email@gmail.com", "email2@gmail.com", "email3@gmail.com"?

Comment: @G.hakim I want to be able to enter multiple email addresses with just a separator and then format the output to email@gmail.com /space/ email2@gmail.com /space/ email3@gmail.com

Comment: It still looks unclear to me. The space already is *a separator*

Comment: 1 - the formatting is as you typing or after for example hit enter ? 2 - do you use MVVM pattern or not (i.e: use code behind) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question!

```
string entry = Entry.Text;
List<string> arrayfromEntry = new List<string>();
          if (entry.Contains(" ") == true){
          arrayfromEntry = entry.Split(new char[] { ' ' }).ToList();
          }
          else{
            arrayfromEntry = entry.Split(new char[] { ',' }).ToList();
          }
          for (int i = 0; i < arrayfromEntry.Count(); i++){
            arrayfromEntry[i] = '"' + arrayfromEntry[i] + '"'; 
          }
string f = (string.Join(", ",arrayfromEntry));
f = f.Remove(f.Count()-2,2);
f = f+'"';
textToLabel = f;
```

Where `Entry.Text` is the text from your entry and `textToLabel` changes the text of your label, this should work.

Comment: I am getting an output of **"email1@gmail.com", "email2@gmail.com** there is no last quotation mark on the last email

Comment: Happy to help, loot.

Comment: What if I want the separator is a comma instead of a space but  the same output? what will I change to your code?

Comment: The code should work with both, if it doesn't let me know.

Comment: I am getting an output of "email@gmail.com", "email2@gmail.co" it is eliminating the last letter of what i input

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178825/discussion-between-jamesfdearborn-and-loot-verge).

Answer (score 1):

Based on the @jamesfdearborn answer, but using StringBuilder instead

```
string entry == "aaaa@ttttt.com,bbbb@ttttttyyy.com,tttt@errrer.com,yyyyyy@rrrttr.com,uuuuu@yuyuy.com";
var inputSeparator = ','; //comma is the separator in this case you can change it 
var outputSeparator = ',';

var arrayfromEntry = entry.Split(inputSeparator).ToList();

var sb = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0; i < arrayfromEntry.Count(); i++)
{
    sb.AppendFormat("\"{0}\"{1}",arrayfromEntry[i],outputSeparator);    
}

sb.Remove(sb.ToString().Count()-1, 1);

sb.ToString() //result here 
//output
//"aaaa@ttttt.com","bbbb@ttttttyyy.com","tttt@errrer.com","yyyyyy@rrrttr.com","uuuuu@yuyuy.com"
```

you can change the output or the the input separator